# Run function with positional and optional arguments in parallel in python

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, parallel-processing

I'm trying to compute various metrics on a Pandas DataFrame using the `apply` method. Since the DataFrame I'm working with is quiet big (1 million rows x 20 columns), I decided to parallelize the computation process.

In order to reproduce the issue I'm having, I'm going to use the iris dataset. Here are the steps:

```
# Step 1: Import all required modules + load iris dataset to Pandas DataFrame

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from multiprocessing import Pool

iris = pd.DataFrame(sns.load_dataset('iris'))

# Step 2: Define function that adds some metric to initial iris DataFrame

def add_metrics(data):
    data['x_1'] = data['species'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
    return data

# Step 3: Define parallelization function

num_partitions = 10 # number of partitions to split dataframe
num_cores = 4 

def parallelize_dataframe(df, func):
    df_split = np.array_split(df, num_partitions)
    pool = Pool(num_cores)
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df

# Step 4: Add metrics to initial iris DataFrame using parallelization function

iris = parallelize_dataframe(iris, add_metrics)
```

The above process works perfectly well as it is **BUT** I want to be able to have additional positional and/or optional arguments in my `add_metrics` function. For example, my `add_metrics` function might look like the following:

```
def add_metrics(data, num, keep = False):
    data['x_1'] = data['species'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
    data['x_2'] = data['sepal_length'].apply(lambda x: x * num)
    if keep == True:
        data['x_3'] = data['sepal_width'].apply(lambda x: x * num)
    return data
```

Now, no matter how I try to call the `parallelize_dataframe` function I'm getting an error. For example:

`iris = parallelize_dataframe(iris, add_metrics(iris, 2, keep = True))` throws a `TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable`.

I'm fairly new to Python so I don't know what is going wrong here and how to fix my problem. I know the example I chose does not require parallel processing as the iris dataset only contains 150 observation. I used it to easily reproduce my problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may want to show actual processing instead of *some (meaningless) metric* as `DataFrame.apply` is a hidden loop and should be avoided with big data like 10M rows. You may be able to optimize processing like vectorization. With your example, no `apply` (i.e., loop) is needed.

Comment: I agree with @Parfait, for any substantial optimizations we need to consider the entire program.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `functools.partial` to set variables in your function before passing to map.

```
def add(x,y):
    return(x+y)

a = [1, 2, 3]
import functools
map(functools.partial(add, y=2), a) # map object [3, 4, 5]
```